# How to achieve constant url in browser angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to maitain a constant url in browser
 Even when user moves around different path the url in browser should not change let's say appname/home.do
I see that the path  name gets appended after home.do

Answer (score 2):

Requirement seems strange,
But to achieve it try using your own location Strategy.
Create One Service & ,

```
export class MyPlatform extends LocationStrategy {

prepareExternalUrl(internal:string):string{
 //return whatever URL u want to return
}

}
```

And in your app.module.ts
write in providers section

```
providers:[ {provide:LocationStrategy,useClass:MyPlatform }]
```

Comment: What are the implications of using a custom `LocationStrategy`, does it lose history tracking?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [skipLocationChange](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html#!#skipLocationChange-anchor) which specifies a **boolean** value to be `true` or `false`.

**Usage**

```
// Navigate silently to /view
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { skipLocationChange: true }); //as mentioned in the docs
```

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/9608/commits/f6fd63be1f36af095d5d9a50bd4d57069d013d39) is a pull request for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide (instead of the default `PathLocationStrategy`) a custom `LocationStrategy` implementation, that doesn't use the pushState API and just internally manages the history.